# How To Change An Array Of Objects In This Case

Tags: javascript

Hey guys iam New To Stack and
iam trying to achieve an array of object manipulation which iam unable to find a proper solution.Any help would be appreciated
Down Below Is My Inital Object

```
[0:{albert:{
         title:'Forecast'},
1:{andrew:{
         title:'Forecast2'}]
```

So down below is what iam trying to achieve

```
{albert:{
         title:'Forecast'},
 andrew:{
         title:'Forecast2'}}
```

Is it possible to convert the inital object to my expected one?

Comment: the initial object is actually an array. So you should just do something like: `let result = initialObject[0]`

Comment: but what is multiple objects are present

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: I invite you to better understand arrays on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: Please add more and proper details.

Comment: I agree. Read mdn. Better detail. not possible to comprehent

Comment: now the question is different and it's about merging the objects coming from an array: `Object.assign( ...initialObject);`

Answer (score 2):

What you have is an array. You can easily convert it to an object like so:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    albert: {
      title: "Forecast"
    }
  },
  {
    andrew: {
      title: "Forecast2"
    }
  }
];
const obj = {};
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
  const key = Object.keys(arr[i])[0];
  obj[key] = arr[i][key];
}

console.log(obj);
```

I'm assuming that each object will only have one top-level key. And also, you are missing brackets in your array.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Object.assign` method and `ES6 Destructuring` syntax to achieve it.

Here is an example:

```
const arr = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }];
const obj = Object.assign({}, ...arr); // obj is { a: 1, b: 2 }
```